# Sphinx acoustic model on windows 8

Tags: windows, cmusphinx

I am creating an acoustic model on windows 8. I have downloaded the sphinxbase pocket shinx and sphinxtrain. Now when i try to execute "python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain -t an4 setup" command, it says that "failed to find sphinxtrain binaries." I wanted to know that are these different for windows? But if they are same then why it is not finding them. I have also updated the path variable.and i tried to download package with binaries:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinxtrain/5prealpha/sphinxtrain-5prealpha-win32.zip/download it said !   : The archive is either in unknown format or damaged

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. There was a problem in my visual studio and when it solved the error removed.